# Unable to download remote image with PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Edit: I contact the support at scrapestack and confirmed that their api doesn't support image files.

I am trying to download a remote image using CURL with php. Below is my code. But whenever I try to open the downloaded image, I always get:

```
Cannot read this file. This is not a valid bitmap file, or its format is not currently supported.
```

Anyone know what is wrong with my code? Thank you.

```
$image ="http://api.scrapestack.com/scrape?access_key=TOKEN-HERE&url=https://i.imgur.com/Cbiu8Ef.png";
$imageName = pathinfo( $image, PATHINFO_BASENAME );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $image );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING, false);
$source = curl_exec( $ch );
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
file_put_contents( $imageName, $source );
```

I am not able to open the file, when I tried to open it with sublime, it is stuck at Loading Image. When I open it with notepad, I got the following that looks like PNG image, but it is not a valid image. File starts with 
    �PNG

```
IHDR       �   q�I�    IDATx�k�]�u�o��(��_�M��m�8:���_r�G
```

You can see the file here: https://gofile.io/?c=cfsYf2

Looks like the problem is making the curl request through Scrapestack, because if I point the curl to image url directly, the image is downloaded correctly, like below:

```
$image ="https://i.imgur.com/Cbiu8Ef.png";
```

Comment: if you open the downloaded file with a **text editor** what do you get? if it is readable text edit your question and post the text as well.

Comment: @Paolo, the file is very big, I don't think it is a good idea to post the whole content here, so I uploaded it online. Please take a look if you can

Comment: looks like a corrupt png image, see **my answer**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the response you get is a **corrupt** PNG image.

If you are using PHP with version **prior of 5.1.3** you need to specify an additional option for binary data transfers, like images:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
```

---

If the above options doesn't solve the issue you may try setting

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_CONTENT_DECODING, false);
```

in case the response has the `Content-Type` header set wrong letting curl do unwanted decoding on the raw output.

Comment: @LukeMark I edited my answer. See the update. Btw: if you point curl to the image `https://i.imgur.com/Cbiu8Ef.png` instead of **scrapestack** do you still get a corrupt image or a valid PNG? If you get a valid image then there are issues with **scrapestack**. If you get an invalid image in both cases then there is something wrong in your environment - but the code you posted is correct. hope it helps.

Comment: I tried both of the code you suggested above. Still the same error. If I was to point the curl to the image directly, it works. But if I try to get it through scrapestack, it doesn't work.

Comment: @LukeMark seem like a **scrapestack** issue. If scrapestack is serving screwed up data there's not much you can do except opening a support ticket / submit a bug report

Comment: I did and confirmed they don't support image files.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I played around with scrapestack a bit more today, it doesn't seem to support image scraping. It is best if you can reach out to their customer support and find out.

@Towsif is right, you are trying to get the page, not the actual image. I put something together really quick, try and see if this works for you.

```
$queryString = http_build_query([
  'access_key' => 'replace this with your own token',
  'url' => 'https://i.imgur.com/Cbiu8Ef.png',
]);

$ch = curl_init(sprintf('%s?%s', 'http://api.scrapestack.com/scrape', $queryString));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
$image_source = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
file_put_contents( 'Cbiu8Ef.png' , $image_source );
```

Comment: thank you for helping. I tried your code, but it is producing the same file as my file, which is not a valid image file.

Comment: @Paolo, I don't have enough reputation to add comment to your answer, so I will add it here. I don't think binary transfer is the problem, I had some time to play around with the code this morning and I believe the issue is that the request is being make from http://api.scrapestack.com/scrape. If I use the above code and go to the image url directly, I can download the image fine. Luke Mark, do what Paolo suggested, it doesn't hurt to try, maybe I am wrong

Comment: you are right, any idea why this is happening? I can't figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this url.

```
$image ="http://api.scrapestack.com/scrape?access_key=TOKEN-HERE&url=https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4vJV.jpg";
```

If you go to this url

https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4vJV.jpg

You will see the image page but *NOT* the image path. `pathinfo()` function does not work here and raises error.

If you right click on that image and *Open image in new tab* you will then see the image path, in this case that is

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz1p0.png

So you may try with this url

```
$image ="http://api.scrapestack.com/scrape?access_key=TOKEN-HERE&url=https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz1p0.png";
```

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I copied the wrong line. In my php file, I am using the image url, not the page url

Comment: You're welcome. If it works for you, then please accept the answer.